# Retrieve Real time database Counter Value with transactions

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions

I'm setting up a counter for a button "submit" to count products quantity in firebase database,it should increment the quantity +1

I have tried transactions for that and  it works.

I need to retrieve the last value stored in the database.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button submit, fetch;
    DatabaseReference rootRef, demoRef;
    TextView demoValue;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        demoValue =  findViewById(R.id.tvValue);
        submit =  findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        fetch =  findViewById(R.id.btnFetch);

        //database reference pointing to root of database
        rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("demo").child("Products");
        demoRef=rootRef.child("quantity");





        //database reference pointing to demo node

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



demoRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
    @Override
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
        Long value = mutableData.getValue(Long.class);
        if (value == null) {
            mutableData.setValue(0);
        }
        else {
            mutableData.setValue(value - 1);
        }

        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                           DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    }
});

            }
        });

        fetch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rootRef.child("quantity").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        Integer value = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);



                        demoValue.setText(value);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When i press the fetch button to show value stored in the database , the app do nothing or crashes!!

My Logcat

```
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xa2
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:472)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4465)
        at com.example.ahmed.firebaseupdatequatity.MainActivity$2$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:95)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:183)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Check my database structure here:

[image]

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please also add your database structure.

Comment: i think to retrieve data from a transaction like that, it has a diffrent coding @AlexMamo

Comment: Please add the error that you get when the app crashes and the database structure.

Comment: done added my logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xa2
```

Because you are trying to pass to the `setText()` method an Integer rather than a String. To solve this, please change the follwing line of code:

```
demoValue.setText(value);
```

to

```
demoValue.setText(String.valueOf(value));
```

or

```
demoValue.setText("" + value);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but i have one more question...is there a way to make my text view update in the realtime ..i mean when i press button fetch it shows the last value stored..perfect,but what i need when i press submit to decrement the counter i want the change work in realtime with the text view

Comment: You're welcome. In this case, you should use a [ValueEventListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ValueEventListener), to get the data in realtime. So please make your own attempt given the information in my comment and ask another question if something else comes up. Cheers!

Comment: i have add a ValueEventListener to my TextView

Comment: You need to use `addValueEventListener()` and not `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`.